# Select SQL statement on related tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, relational-database

I have two tables T1 and T2. I want to select  all rows from T2 table where t1_id not equal to any id in T1 table. This is not working:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.t1_id, t2.data FROM T2.t2, T1.t1 WHERE t2.t1_id != t1.id
```

Comment: SELECT x.* FROM x LEFT JOIN y ON y.id = x.id WHERE y.id IS NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use subquery with NOT IN clause as below:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.t1_id, t2.data 
FROM T2 t2
WHERE t2.t1_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id
                       FROM T1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **LEFT JOIN** to fetch all records from left table and add where condition with checking of null value of second table to find unmatched records of left table

Try this:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.t1_id, t2.data 
FROM T2.t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN T1.t1 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```

Comment: I need ti fetch rows where t1_id  not equal to any id in T1. null is not eaxctly that result what I want...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.t1_id, t2.data 
FROM T2.t2
LEFT JOIN T1.t1 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
GROUP BY t2.id, t2.t1_id, t2.data
HAVING sum(t1.id is not null) = 0
```